# Can I make JPA output a physical DB transaction via a SQL statement

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I understand that JPA provides a layer of abstraction for transactions, and in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/FlushModeType.html) it says that

> the persistence provider is responsible for ensuring that all updates to the state of all entities in the persistence context which could potentially affect the result of the query are visible to the processing of the query.

It goes on to say that the mechanism for achieving this is not specified:

> The persistence provider implementation may achieve this by flushing those entities to the database or by some other means.

I use Spring Boot, Hibernate and Postgres. Postgres allows specifying constraints, but these constraints can be relaxed in transactions, i.e. they are only checked at the end of a transaction.

Of course, Postgres does not know about JPA/Hibernate transactions unless they explicitly issue a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement. In fact, I verified that if I do issue such statement, constraints are only checked at the end of the transaciton.

I know that the way to manage transactions is to use `@Transactional`. My question is: is there a way to tell Spring or Hibernate to generate  `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` SQL statements when I use `@Transactional`? It would be even better if I could do this with the JPA API.

Comment: Transactions are typically managed using the `@Transactional` annotation in Spring/JPA

Comment: Yes. I need that annotation to cause a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement so Postgres knows to delay verifying the constraints. How do I do that, if it's even possible? I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Well, there is only way to start a transaction. So Spring (or the JDBC driver) will have to send a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` somehow.

Comment: Do you know if this is possible? If you do, can you please share how to do it?

Comment: `@Transactional` will handle that.